# How can I paginate by a common value with Django and REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Background:**

Hi, folks. I have a model, `Transplant`, which describes which plant species were transplanted at a given time. Here are my models, boiled down to a simple form:

```py
class Species(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Transplant(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    species = models.ManyToManyField(Species, related_query_name='transplants')
```

**Problem:**

I'd like to serve results from my API paginated by the date component of my `DateTimeField`, and showing the date and a list of distinct species. There are an arbitrary number of transplants per day, and transplants are done on arbitrary days.

Given the following transplants:

```py
[
    { 'datetime': '2019-07-01 10:00:00', 'species': ['Lettuce', 'Kale'] },
    { 'datetime': '2019-07-01 12:00:00', 'species': ['Basil', 'Kale', 'Chard'] },
    { 'datetime': '2019-07-01 15:00:00', 'species': ['Lettuce'] },

    { 'datetime': '2019-07-02 11:00:00', 'species': ['Spinach'] },
    { 'datetime': '2019-07-02 16:15:00', 'species': ['Lettuce'] },

    { 'datetime': '2019-07-05 09:00:00', 'species': ['Lettuce', 'Kale'] },
    { 'datetime': '2019-07-05 12:00:00', 'species': ['Arugula', 'Spinach'] },
]
```

I'd like these results (if `page_size = 2`):

```py
# page 1
[
    { 'date': '2019-07-01', 'species': ['Lettuce', 'Kale', 'Basil', 'Chard'] },
    { 'date': '2019-07-02', 'species': ['Spinach', 'Lettuce'] },
]

# page 2
[
    { 'date': '2019-07-05', 'species': ['Lettuce', 'Kale', 'Arugula', 'Spinach'] },
]
```

**What I've Tried:**

What I'm doing now is querying for distinct dates, grabbing a page of those dates, querying *again* for all the transplants on those date, and serializing, like so:

```py
class TransplantViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model            = Transplant
    queryset         = Transplant.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GenericTransplantSerializer
    lookup_field     = 'pk'
    # ...

    @list_route(methods=('get'))
    def by_date(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Annotate dates
        date_qs = Transplants.objects.order_by('-datetime')\
            .annotate(date=Trunc('datetime', 'day', output_field=DateField()))\
            .values_list('date', flat=True)\
            .distinct()
        # Get a single page of dates
        dates = paginator.paginate_queryset(dates_qs, request)
        # Get matching transplants
        transplants = Transplant.objects.filter(datetime__date__in=dates)\
            .annotate(date=Trunc('datetime', 'day', output_field=DateField()))
        # Build a dict formatted as
        # { 'date_1': [t1, t2, ...], 'date_2': [t1, t2, ...], ... }
        transplants_by_date = {}
        for t in transplants:
            transplants_by_date.setdefault(t.date, []).append(t)
        # Transpose to a list of dicts in the format
        # { 'date': 'date_1': 'species': [t1, t2, ...], ... }
        transplants_by_date = [{'date': k, 'species': v} for k,v in transplants_by_date.items()]
        # Serialize
        serial = TransplantByDateSerializer(transplants_by_date,
                                            many=many,
                                            context={'request':request})

        return Response(serial.data)
```

Is there a less ham-fisted way of doing this? This works, but it wreaks, makes an extra trip to the DB, and isn't terribly performant (actual models and queries are more complicated, helped somewhat by prefetching).

I've attempted to use something like `window w as (partition by date_part('day', datetime) order by datetime desc)` (implemented with Django) to do it in one trip to the DB, but I haven't been able to turn my results into `Model` instances or avoid rolling my own dictionaries, as above.

I'm open to changing my `DateTimeField` to a `DateField` if that will help, since in my actual, more complicated models, the exact time is captured elsewhere. This `Transplant` model is meant to be more of a summary of activities.

I'm using Django 2.1.7, DRF 3.7.3, and Python 3.6.8, all running on top of PostgreSQL 11, if that's important.

Any advice is appreciated! Thanks!